How to create a compatible encoding for the Blackmagic Media Express application using ffmpeg
I'm using the Blackmagic Media Express application frequently but now I'm stuck trying to transcode files using ffmpeg that will be able to play in the BME app. It seems that the BME application is extremely picky in which files to accept. I keep getting the error "The file format is not supported." I'm quite sure I've nailed down the exact ProRes codec settings for it to work. And I have set all the metadata tags that ffmpeg allows me to set. But I'm still out of luck so far .....
Here's the command string:
INPUT.MXF -vf "scale=in_color_matrix=bt709:out_color_matrix=bt709,format=yuv422p10le" -c:v prores -profile:v 3 -pix_fmt yuv422p10le -metadata:s:v:0 handler_name="Apple Video Media Handler" -metadata:s:v:0 vendor_id="appl" -metadata:s:v:0 encoder="Apple ProRes 422 HQ" -metadata:s:a:0 handler_name="Apple Sound Media Handler" -metadata:s:t:0 handler_name="Time Code Media Handler" -metadata creation_time="now" -c:a pcm_s16le -ar 48000 -ac 2 -timecode 00:00:00:00 -f mov OUTPUT.mov 
The codecs that are supported by Media Express for playback are the same as supported by the Blackmagic decklink hardware. In my case this is ProRes 422 HQ. But BME will also accept exports from NLE's such as Avid and Media Composer and Adobe Premiere. It seems that those applications have the ability to write the Writing_Library metadata. In the files that do work it says writing_library: Apple_Quicktime. But with the ffmpeg transcode it says Writing_application: Lavf61.1.100.
Any help would be very much appreciated !)

https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=41169

Please include what you concluded BME supports, the source for that, what you chose to target, [and how you included that in the ffmpeg params]. Then it will be verifiable by readers and potential answerers (even people not familiar with BME).

The codecs that are supported by Media Express are the same as supported by the Blackmagic decklink hardware. In my case this is ProRes 422 HQ. But BME will also accept exports from NLE's such as Avid and Media Composer and Adobe Premiere. It seems that those applications have the ability to write the Writing_Library metadata. In the files that do work it says writing_library: Apple_Quicktime. But with the ffmpeg transcode it says Writing_application: Lavf61.1.100.

Welcome to SuperUser. Requested information should be added to the question itself. A big factor to getting good answers is having a good question. So your goal right now is to make your question better, and a big part of doing that is adding information community members request to the question itself. Use the EDIT button to do that.
